# How to make \@namedef within a tabular cell have wider scope?

Tags: tables, scoping

How can I make `\@namedef` stated within a tabular cell define a name that can be reused outside that cell? For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter

  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \hline
  1 & \@namedef{name}{content}\@nameuse{name} \\
  2 &                         \@nameuse{name} \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}

\makeatother
\end{document}
```

The current output is:

[image]

But the expected output would be:

[image]

Comment: you could use `\global\@namedef` but then it will have global scope (it also makes assumptions about the implementation of `\@namedef` but the assumptions are true...)

Comment: Thanks. It works. Could `\global` get me into trouble (besides namespace issues)?  I'm asking this because I'm trying to solve a bug report about my `clipboard` package, and I would rather not release a new version that could give rise to more trouble.

Comment: well it just means that it's as if you'd done  \@namedef{name}{content} in the preamble so it is in scope for the whole document, probably safe enough if the names you are redefining are safe  `\global\@namedef{box}{content}` wouldn't be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
\global\@namedef
```

but then it will have global scope. It also makes assumptions about the implementation of `\@namedef` but the assumptions are true, but for example you can not use `\global` in general before macros, `\global\newcommand` does not work at all.